# How can I check the content transfer encoding of incoming emails using Zend framework

Tags: email, zend-framework, content-encoding

How can I detect the content-transfer-encoding of emails in the inbox using Zend framework.
I need to check to make sure whether a message is qyoted printable content so I can run a decode upon it somehow. The encoding doesn't appear in the message object that I get from using Zend_Mail_Imap_Storage::getMessage

please help

Comment: how do you know the header doesn't appear in the message object?

Are you doing `$msg->getHeader('content-transfer-encoding');` and getting nothing?